# Does TaskCompletionSource guarantee awaiting code will resume on the thread which called TCS.TrySetResult?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have a method which wraps a callback using TaskCompletionSource like this:

```
public Task<int> TestMethod(int argument)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    var task = tcs.Task;

    LegacyMethodWithCallback(argument, (returnValue) => tcs.TrySetResult(returnValue));

    return task;
}
```

And then I await on that method:

```
async int CallingMethod()
{
    var returnValue = await TestMethod(5);
    Console.WriteLine(returnValue);
    return returnValue;
}
```

EDIT: LegacyMethodWithCallback is a method communicating with a server using the network. The callback runs on a thread belonging to our proprietary thread pool (which is a reason to implement a custom SynchronizationContext). The custom SynchronizationContext is basically blank except its Post method enqueues the delegate into out thread pool. Here is implementation of the SC that should demonstrate when Post is called:

```
internal class ServiceSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Post " + d + ": " + state + " for " + this.serviceLogic.ServiceLogicId);

        // Enqueue the delegate into our thread pool
    }
}
```

I have implemented my own synchronization context, but I was suprised to see that CallingMethod appears to resume immediately on the same thread which called the TrySetResult (and therefore the same thread which invoked the callback). I originally expected the continuation to be Post-ed via the SynchronizationContext.

**Is this behavior guaranteed or are there any cases in which the SynchronizationContext (or any other thread) is invoked? If this behavior is not fully deterministic, can I control it somehow?**

I thoroughly inspected the call stack at the moment when CallingMethod resumes and it appears that the SynchronizationContext is not even considered (but there is still some code that cannot be easily looked into), so it appears that this behavior is inded guaranteed. Am I correct?

Comment: Which thread is used to resume execution after the `await` within the `async` method *should* be a local decision within that method (e.g. controlled by using `ConfigureAwait`) and, as you allude to, also based on any `SynchronizationContext`. Can you create a *complete* code sample? (E.g. a [mcve])

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure, since you're not showing quite enough, but it appears that your callback runs on a thread-pool thread, while the scheduler for the `await` is also associated with the thread-pool. This means that the scheduler is allowed to run the "continuation" synchronously on the same thread. You're not showing your synchronization context, so we can't tell how the code runs through there - most likely, you allowed the task to run synchronously (which is incorrect in this case). Other common issue is losing the synchronization context at some point.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Is there anything in particular my code sample is missing? I believe it contains everything needed to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: In general, try to make a full sample we can run. That makes it much more likely that someone is going to help you - and often solves your problem outright, since by whittling the problem down to the barest essentials usually helps you find the problem itself :)

Comment: @MatějZábský: If there's a `SynchronizationContext.Current` before the `await` in `CallingMethod`, then the continuation will be posted to that SyncCtx. I am suspecting there's a bug in code you haven't posted. Please post a **complete** example.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this behavior guaranteed or are there any cases in which the SynchronizationContext (or any other thread) is invoked?

SynchronizationContext, if present, is always used by the awaiting code (unless specified otherwise by `ConfigureAwait(false)`). That means you can't assume the awaiting code will run on your thread if you can't control the awaiting code.

There are a few reasons for you continuations not to be inlined on the same thread. One is whether `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` is used. Others like the current `SynchronizationContext` and `TaskScheduler` are in [`IsValidLocationForInlining`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs,a9f997f119a2bb07,references):

```
internal static bool IsValidLocationForInlining
{
    get
    {
        // If there's a SynchronizationContext, we'll be conservative and say 
        // this is a bad location to inline.
        var ctx = SynchronizationContext.CurrentNoFlow;
        if (ctx != null && ctx.GetType() != typeof(SynchronizationContext)) return false;

        // Similarly, if there's a non-default TaskScheduler, we'll be conservative
        // and say this is a bad location to inline.
        var sched = TaskScheduler.InternalCurrent;
        return sched == null || sched == TaskScheduler.Default;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sure the synchronization context is present in my case, and one the call stack I can see that Post of no synchronization context (mine or otherwise) was used. Why, if it is supposed to be used "always"? I am not using ConfigureAwait(false).

Comment: @MatějZábský are you using the same SC in both methods?

Comment: @MatějZábský also, is the task already completed when awaited?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. No, it is not completed. It is a network communication function (which I have padded with some sleeps on the server side, to be sure).

Comment: @MatějZábský [this code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs,a9f997f119a2bb07) decides whether you can inline an await continuation. It checks for a `SynchronizationContext` and a `TaskScheduler`. You may still end up on the same thread without inlining but that would can't be guaranteed.